# What is the meaning of $2^\sqrt{3}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

What is the meaning of $2^\sqrt{3}$ ?

one can explain $2^3=2\times2\times2$

But how can I explain $2^\sqrt{3}$ etc. ?

How can I explain non-integer powers? I do not want the value. I need to know whether there is an explanation for this in real analysis.

Comment: how can you explain $2^{3/2 }$?

Comment: Do you have any trouble with $2^{1/3}$? If not, you can always introduce a sequence of rational numbers converging to $\sqrt{3}$

Comment: yes, I do not want the answer. Is there an explanation for this in real analysis.

Comment: What do you mean by "explanation"?

Comment: https://www.maa.org/external_archive/devlin/devlin_0708_08.html

Comment: Look up 'the singularity'. All will become clear soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can also define $2^{\sqrt{3}}$ as follows. First, $2^k$ for integral $k$ is clear. If $k>0$ is an integer, it is clear how to define $2^{1/k}$: as the unique positive real $k^{\mathrm{th}}$ root of $2$. Then, for $r$ any positive real, choose a sequence $a_n = \frac{p_n}{q_n}$, where $p_n, q_n$ are integers, converging to $r$. Then $2^r:=\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^{a_n}$.

Comment: I should add that it requires at least a little work to show that $2^r$ is in fact well-defined; in other words, that you reach the same limit no matter what sequence of rational $a_n$ you choose.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to define $x^y$ for real $y$ and $x>0$. Here are three popular variations:

- $x^y=\exp(y\ln x)$, where $\exp$ is defined through, say, a power series
- $x^y=\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{y_n}$ where $y_n$ is a sequence of rationals converging to $y$, and $x^{y_n}$ is defined through roots and repeated multiplication
- The function $y\mapsto x^y$ is the unique continuous homomorphism from the group of real numbers with addition to the group of positive real numbers with multiplication which sends $1$ to $x$ (using the standard topology)

Either one gives the same result: $2^{\sqrt3}\approx 3.322$.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning is $e^{\ln(2)\sqrt 3}=\exp(\ln(2)\sqrt 3)$. The exponential is a well defined function.

Comment: LaTeX tip: use `\ln` to get $\ln$

Comment: and \exp for exp

Comment: I think if the OP is asking what $2^{irrational}$ means, the OP isn't likely to know what $\exp(x)$ means.  Perhaps you should explain what it is.